# Stop windows from being rearranged when an monitor is disconnected

Tags: x11, monitors, window-management

I have two laptops and just got an KVM to switch between them.

But on my Linux Ubuntu 16, when I switch the screen rearranges and moves all windows around. So when I switch back, I can't work out what is where.

Is it possible to do what Windows does: if a monitor / screen is disconnected, it doesn't move any windows around?

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening here is that X is switching between the resolution of your laptop (e.g. 1366x768) and your larger screen (e.g. 1920x1080).  Each switch requires windows, icons, etc to be moved to fit the new resolution.

Try configuring `xorg.conf` so that X always uses a virtual screen resolution which is the same as your monitor?

e.g. if your screen is 1920x1080, then add:

```
Virtual 1920 1080
```

to the `[Display]` subsection of your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

`man xorg.conf` has this to say:

> ```
> Virtual  xdim ydim
> ```
>
> This optional entry specifies the virtual screen resolution to be
>   used.  xdim must be a multiple of either 8 or 16 for  most  drivers,
>   and a multiple of 32 when running in monochrome mode.  The given value
>   will be rounded down if this is not the case.
>
> Video modes which are
>   too large for the specified virtual size will be rejected.   If  this
>   entry  is not present, the virtual screen resolution will be set to
>   accommodate all the valid video modes given in the Modes entry.
>
> Some
>   drivers/hardware combinations do not support virtual screens.   Refer 
>   to  the  appropriate driver-specific documentation for details.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you do this, then you will have to scroll the desktop to see the bottom-most and right-most portions when using the laptop's built-in screen - as far as X is concerned, the desktop is 1920x1080 and you have a 1366x768 view of it.   You may find this to be even more annoying than having the windows move around when switching screens.